# Next.js-express dynamic routing causes page reload

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I have a blog application created with next js using an express custom browser. When i click on a Link to route to '/blog/article-1' it refreshes the page on arriving at that page. How do i avoid this?

**server.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const port = 80;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const compression = require('compression');

app.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(compression());
    server.get('/blog', (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/blog', req.query));
    server.get('/blog/:postslug', (req, res) => {
      const params = { postslug: req.params.postslug }
      return app.render(req, res, '/blog/post', params)
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

**File which links to articles**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default (props) => {

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Link href={`/blog/${dynamicPostSlug}`}>
        <a>
          Go to article
        </a>
      </Link>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

**File where post appears**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import 'isomorphic-unfetch';

class post extends Component {

  static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost/api/posts/${req.params.postslug}`, {
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
      });
      const json = await res.json();
      return { data: json.data };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err');
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <PostContentComesHere data={data}/>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(post);
```

[I have already checked the next.js docs and it has this implementation which uses the node http module.](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-url-object-routing/server.js) I implemented this code on express by copying some parts from the documentation example. However it still seems to cause a page reload when i go to the article page using a .

Comment: <a>Go to article</a> did you remove anchor tag  and try?

Comment: the <a> tag is required for link to work. https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#with-link

Comment: May this help you https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2833#issuecomment-414919347

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace

```
<Link 
 href={`/blog/${dynamicPostSlug}`}>
```

with

```
<Link 
 href={`/blog/post?postslug=${dynamicPostSlug}`} 
 as={`/blog/${dynamicPostSlug}`}>
```

The `getInitialProps` should get query out of paramenters instead of req.

```
static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost/api/posts/${query.postslug}`, {
        method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
      });
      const json = await res.json();
      return { data: json.data };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey. So there seems to be a new issue arising with this answer. In the method  `static async getInitialProps({ req })` the req parameter is giving undefined.

Comment: @Muljayan use `query` instead `static async getInitialProps({ query })`

Comment: Did this slove the issue?? Still on my side page is refreshed.

Comment: This solution is missing a critical part. The `href` has to include square brakets `[]` around the dynamic file. Example: `/blog/[post]?postslug=${dynamicPostSlug}`